# flutter connecting android device Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I am connecting my android device (samsung) to android studio for my flutter app.

When I type `flutter run -v` in the terminal, I get this error[image: Terminal output]

I installed the NDK tools and latest version, restarted the "android studio" and the pc and I still have the same error.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Open Android Studio -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> Show Package Details -> Select "NDK" -> select missing package -> Apply